# Shadow of ImageView or CardView like Google Play Games

Tags: java, android, android-cardview, google-play-games, android-studio-3.3

Currently this is this the way i am showing shadow under my cardview in my projects :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:id="@+id/item_card"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
  app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
  app:cardElevation="5dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

which in result looks like this :

[image]

which is pretty basic and i know we can control the shadow color in higher api but in PlayGames by Google
the app is doing the same even in API level 21, How ?

For Example this :
[image]

How the colors are captured and settled as the shadow of that CardView or ImageView ?
Can i bring this to my app ?

Please share your Knowledge before flagging the question.

Comment: no one ? no idea ?

Answer (score 0):

For API 28 and higher "you can control the elevation shadow color using the outline[Ambient|Spot]ShadowColor view attributes and the [spot|ambient]shadowAlpha theme attributes". see: https://twitter.com/crafty/status/1011918657759469569
And you cand find a prototype for older versions here: https://gist.github.com/nickbutcher/1dcde5a989011d01fda491bc9a59c21e#file-blur_shadows-gif

Comment: sorry for late reply, but i already tested this one and this is way beyond, the one by google is wide and caputres more design. you can see the image i posted and can see diffrence between this and crafty's lib.

Comment: I get your point, not sure how it is made exactly. You can try this lib: https://github.com/armcha/ColoredShadowImageView it seems pretty near to the one on Play Game's.

Comment: i found this one https://github.com/yingLanNull/ShadowImageView it's pretty much near to what i need but may have performance issues. Have to check that. Thank you for time.